# MVC Core: Iconfiguration

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-mvc

What does this do and mean? The current [MSDN IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.0) document does not explain.

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) =>
        Configuration = configuration;
```

Comment: Looks like a constructor that sets a property? To the value of the configuration passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a lambda method (constructor). Slightly longer but more familiar form:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) 
{
   Configuration = configuration;
}
```

which is using constructor injection to register an implemtation for `IConfiguration`. When you trace back to Configuration you will see that it is a readonly property. Could have been a _configuration field as well.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET 2 Core, we need to build webhost to host an application. During creation of that host [*by default, creating IWebHostBuilder using CreateDefaultBuilder method*], default configuration is constructed that includes app configuration, logging, default server and few other settings.

Please refer this link https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-configuration/

The way, assigns Configuration variable, that is lambda expression, and MSDN says

> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any)
>   on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression
>   or statement block on the other side.

Please refer this link for more detail - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

The statement, given by you, assigns lambda expression argument to outer variable [a variable declared outside lambda function].

In above link, "[Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions)" section serves better understanding.